# How to insert string that contains " character in sqlite ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, special-characters

i am using following code but sqlite giving me error

```
 NSArray* a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
              @"\""
              @"\\ \"",
              nil];
quantity=[quantity stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[a objectAtIndex:0 ] withString:[a objectAtIndex:1]];
queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO SHOPINGLIST (QUANTITY) VALUES (\"%@\")",quantity];
```

it gives error that:- near "diax1": syntax error in query INSERT INTO SHOPINGLIST 
original quantity is =1 slice,medium(4-1/2"diax1/8"thick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert special characters in SQLite in iOS, use placeholders like (also please check which special characters are allowed in Sqlite):

```
queryString = @"INSERT INTO SHOPINGLIST (QUANTITY) VALUES (?)";
sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, queryString, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, [quantity UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
  // Use sqlite3_bind_text for string values. For other type of values, check sqlite documentation.
 // .... And So on.

    }
```

Comment: thank you,,its working..
one more problem, how to insert float value because above statement is only working for string.
i mean for float value should i replace (?) or what?

Comment: For float value use sqlite3_bind_double. Check this link : http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html. I suggest You should follow some sqlite tutorial to clear your concepts.

Comment: @GauravSingh what is quantity?

Comment: @AugustinJose In my example, quantity is `NSString`

Answer (score 1):

for double value, use this:-

```
sqlite3_bind_double(compiledStatement, 1, [quantity UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```