# SQLite has not taking Double Quotes in iOS, how can i manage it?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

Im newly working on SQLite Functionality. Add, Edit, Update, Delete Functionality working, But Sqlite has not taking the Double Quotes.How can i manage the code in iOS.

My insert query is

```
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (sfile,sfields,scondition,jsondata,ssort,startpos,endpos) VALUES ('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@')", sfile,sfields,scondition,jsondata,ssort,startpos,endpos];
    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
    sqlite3_reset(statement);
}
return NO;
```

But it Accepting only double quotes not an single quotes. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use placeholders / prepared statements. This is a common problem of trying to incorrectly build an SQL string containing [user] data which leads to SQL Injection and "queries that stop working when quotes are used". Which API is being used to access the SQLite database?

Comment: How can i use the place holders in SQL string please explain.

Comment: Which API is being used to access the SQLite database?

Comment: If using the native API see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267347/how-to-insert-string-that-contains-character-in-sqlite-ios

Comment: INSERT_TABLE_STMT(tableName , columnsList , rowValues)          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@ (%@) VALUES (%@)",tableName,columnsList,rowValues]

Comment: One more Type im using.     NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (sfile,sfields,scondition,jsondata,ssort,startpos,endpos) VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")", sfile,sfields,scondition,jsondata,ssort,startpos,endpos];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            return YES;
        }

Comment: @nandukathmandi To edit the question, click "edit".

Comment: @nandukathmandi Manually building the SQL with values like that is where the problem is. See the linked question for how to correctly build a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example how to delete and insert using quotes:

```
-(void)saveMyStatus:(NSString*)status{
    NSString *dbPath = [DatabaseHelper databasePath];
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *insertSql1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete from %@",[DatabaseHelper UserTable]];
        const char *insertStmt1 = [insertSql1 UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertStmt1, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE){
            NSLog(@"status removed");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@" status remove failed");
            NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_errmsg(db)]);
        }
        NSString *insertSql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into %@ ( STATUS) values ('%@')",[DatabaseHelper UserTable],status];
        const char *insertStmt = [insertSql UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertStmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            NSLog(@"  status saved");
        else{
            NSLog(@" status save failed");
            NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_errmsg(db)]);
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        if(db)
            sqlite3_close(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But it will works only double quotes. if i entered single quotation data insertion failed. i want irrespective of any data.